# Counting previous nodes returns unexpected results

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, saxon

I'd like to use itemized list instead of hard breaks, see the example:

```
<para>line1<?linebreak?>
line2<?linebreak?>
line3</para>
```

However, I am experiencing weird behavior in my recursive template which prevents processing the second line correctly. I've created simplified test case - not recursive any more. If `count(preceding::processing-instruction('linebreak')) = 0` expression is used this way, nothing is returned, but I would expect the second line.

```
<line>line1</line><node>
line2<?linebreak?>
line3</node>
line2
```

That `<node>` element is for debugging purposes here. It confirms I process expected data.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="para[processing-instruction('linebreak')]">
        <xsl:call-template name="getLine">
            <xsl:with-param name="node" select="./node()"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="getLine">
        <xsl:param name="node"/>

        <line>
            <xsl:copy-of
                select="$node/self::processing-instruction('linebreak')[not(preceding::processing-instruction('linebreak'))]/preceding::node()"
            />
        </line>

        <xsl:call-template name="getSecondLine">
            <xsl:with-param name="node"
                select="$node/self::processing-instruction('linebreak')[not(preceding::processing-instruction('linebreak'))]/following::node()"
            />
        </xsl:call-template>

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="getSecondLine">
        <xsl:param name="node"/>

        <node>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$node"/>
        </node>

        <xsl:copy-of
            select="$node/self::processing-instruction('linebreak')[count(preceding::processing-instruction('linebreak')) = 0]/preceding::node()"
        />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Tested in Saxon HE/EE 9.6.0.7 (in Oxygen XML Editor 18).

Comment: Independently of your current XSLT code, please provide the reference output you expect for your input sample.

Comment: So what is that you want to achieve? In the XSLT/XPath 2.0 world I would consider an itemized list to be simply a sequence of values e.g. `('line1', 'line2', 'line3')`. Do you want to transform that input sample you have into a sequence of strings or perhaps a sequence of `line` elements? Why does that paragraph have both processing instructions to indicate a line break as well as line breaks in the text? Can there be anything more complex than plain text nodes and `<?linebreak?>` processing instructions inside of a `para` element?

Comment: @MartinHonnen Lines are mixed content, not a plain text. I am trying to copy all nodes before PI and pass the rest of nodes to next iteration. However, this 'rest' behaves differently than the first iteration.

Comment: I have not managed to understand what you want to achieve with your templates but as you use XSLT 2.0 and want to identify "groups" of nodes ending with (or starting with) a processing instruction it looks to me like a classic case of `<xsl:template match="para"><xsl:for-each-group select="node()" group-ending-with="processing-instruction('linebreak')">`. See https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#grouping-examples for examples using that approach.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I like you approach, it simplifies the code significantly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The processing of the first linebreak works correctly:

```
<line>
   <xsl:copy-of
     select="$node/self::processing-instruction('linebreak')
              [not(preceding::processing-instruction('linebreak'))]
              /preceding::node()"/>
</line>
```

though only on this sample; on more complex data, you would get the wrong results because you should be using the `preceding-sibling` axis rather than the `preceding` axis.

But the code could be greatly simplified, I would write the `select` expression as:

```
select="$node[self::processing-instruction('linebreak')][1]
        /preceding-sibling::node()"
```

The processing of the second linebreak seems very confused. You are passing the parameter

```
$node/self::processing-instruction('linebreak')
   [not(preceding::processing-instruction('linebreak'))]
   /following::node()"
```

which is effectively

```
select="$node[self::processing-instruction('linebreak')][1]
            /following-sibling::node()"
```

which selects the three nodes

```
line2<?linebreak?>line3
```

(plus whitespace) which you are outputting within a `<node>` element, producing

```
<node>line2<?linebreak?>line3</node>
```

(again ignoring whitespace)

and then you do

```
select="$node/self::processing-instruction('linebreak')
  [count(preceding::processing-instruction('linebreak'))=0]
  /preceding::node()"
```

Here `$node/self::processing-instruction('linebreak')` selects the second of these three nodes, which is the second linebreak processing instruction. The count of preceding (or preceding-sibling) processing instructions is 1, because the one you are dealing with is the second.

I'm not quite sure what you were thinking of, but I suspect your mistake is to think of "preceding" and "following" as selecting relative to the position of the node within the `$node` sequence, rather than relative to other nodes within the original source tree. I would recommend reading the section of an XPath reference book that describes the various axes.

Comment: My biggest mistake here is using slash `$node/self::processing-instruction('linebreak')` instead of brackets `$node[self::processing-instruction('linebreak')]` - the reason why simple [1] failed to select anything so I made things more complicated.

Comment: I still do not understand why selecting `$node[self::processing-instruction('linebreak')][1]/preceding-sibling::node()` in the getSecondLine (modified using a Michael's proposal) returns `line1<?linebreak?>line2` when `line1` doesn't appear anywhere in the passed `$node` param.

Comment: Because $node is a list of nodes, and those nodes have preceding siblings which are not in $node, and by using the preceding-sibling (or preceding) axis you are finding those nodes.

Comment: So even if I pass the tree fragment, it is still linked to the original tree. Ok. In this case I have to change the logic as in my recursion I was hoping preceding-sibling returns the first item of reduced node, which is again reduced in subsequent pass, and so on. Now I am getting infinite loop.

Comment: Yes, binding a variable to a node does not detach the node from its containing tree. You could copy the nodes to detach them, but that's not the best approach.